# How to extract two words from string, that share the same foreword?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to extract letters `s` and `x` from `cell C3` but I only manage to exctract letter `s`:

[image]

How do I return `s, x` in `cell E3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, ","), "B: (.+)"))))
```

[image: 0]